# How to use mkdir -v as defaul mkdir in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, mkdir

In linux ,when I use mkdir -v dir1  ;  linux will show me some information like "dir1 create
" "dir1 exits"  ;

mkdir -v make me fell a "Sense of Security" , i like it .
But I want make "mkdir -v " as the default "mkdir" , everytime I use mkdir , it will show me infomation ;

I think this idea beacause everytime i use "mkdir -v", i feel it unconvinient .

I have try some method , like  export " alias mkdir="mkdir -v "  " in my .bashrc , but it didn't work.

Any easy method to achieve this idea ? Thank you very much !

Comment: `alias mkdir="mkdir -v"` is what you want (and one of the few examples of an alias, rather than a function, being appropriate). Aliases, however, are not expanded by default in non-interactive shells (such as those created to run a script), and aliases are not inherited by subshells or subprocesses. It sounds like you are trying to use the alias somewhere where it will not be expanded or even defined.

Comment: `like export " alias mkdir="mkdir -v " " in my .bashrc , but it didn't work.` did you relogin?

Comment: `export`, however, is *not* used to define an alias; it's only used to mark the export attribute of one or more names (and optionally assign values to those names to create shell variables).

Comment: Questions about interactive shell configuration are better asked over at [UNIX.se]

Comment: You can not _export_ an alias. The alias-definition is local to the shell. If you need it defined in a child process bash, the alias-definition has to be repeated. An alternative you could consider would be to create a shell script named `mkdir`, and arrange to have the directory where it resides, early in your PATH. I personally would not do this (modify a standard command in this way), as this just asks for trouble. I would instead name it differently (for instance, `mkd`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to define the alias to do this

The command below will append to your .bashrc and will accomplish the desired result

```
echo 'alias mkdir="mkdir -v"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Remember to get a new shell or type bash to reload your .bashrc file in your current shell

If once in a while you don't want this behavior just prefix your command with a \

```
\mkdir test
```

The above will ignore the effect of alias just for this one command.

**Sample run**

```
$ alias mkdir='mkdir -v'
$ mkdir test
mkdir: created directory 'test'
$ \mkdir test1
$
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I solve it with this method ；I think may be the problem is  -> I use "" to instead ' '  when i set the alias    so foolish for me to do this  . Any way, Thanks you all , and hope you can have  a good day , all kind people here.

Comment: I am so glad that you were able to make it work. Please accept the answer and close the question. Thanks